# WordPress memory on 3.X

Tags: memory

I'm using the [WP_Overview](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-overview-lite/) plugin to view WordPress' memory limit.

It's showing `Mem: WP 32M (def) Usage 25% 32.59M of PHP Limit 128M`.

However, in my `functions.php`, I have the following line of code: `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT','96M');`.

I've also installed the [Change Memory Limit](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/change-memory-limit/) plugin and tried updating the figure from there, again to 96M.

Despite this, the Overview plugin is still showing 32M.

Three questions in one:

1. Which gets used, the PHP limit or the WP limit?
2. Is this plugin a good way of checking the limit, or should I try a different method?
3. Is this potentially a problem with WP 3.X? I found [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-memory-limit-not-updated) post on WP Support which might imply that it is. Their solution suggests moving the `PHP.INI` but I'm not particularly keen on doing that - surely it can't be safe?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

From quick look (at horribly minified code) plugin just echoes `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` in that place so no idea what is going on for you.

The basic way to retrieve real PHP memory limit (at specific point! it can be changed in runtime) is [`ini_get( 'memory_limit' )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). Related WordPress constants are mostly just a guidelines for WP to stay under.

Comment: I'm currently sitting at 30mb usage, with 32mb WP limit. If a big script is running, is there a chance that it'll be hitting the 32mb limit?